# Why can you not cast an integer to string?

Tags: java, string, int

This is something I never truly understood in Java. Lets say I have:

```
int x = 4;
```

now I can not do this

`functionThatRequiresString(x)` or `functionThatRequiresString((String)x)`

Now I can not pass a function that requires a string the variable `x`. I am also unable to cast it from an int to a string. Now the normal ways of doing this would be:

`Integer.toString(x)` or `String.valueOf(x)`

Now why can I do this though?

`functionThatRequiresString(""+x)`

How is this different from casting an integer to a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting means that you tell the compiler "I have an object of type A here, but I want you to treat it as if it is of type B. Don't give an error because it doesn't look like a B to you".

Casting does not do any conversions (at least not for non-primitive types). If, when running the program, the object really is not of type B, you will get a `ClassCastException`.

You cannot cast an `int` to a `String` because an `int` is simply not a `String` - you can tell the compiler to pretend that it is, but you'll get a `ClassCastException` when you run the program.

The other examples you give will **convert** (not cast) an `int` to a `String`.

Comment: Thank you, my understanding of casting was always that you are converting from one data type to another. So my understanding that it is not that simple of a definition.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness we can look at the compiled byte code:

```
int i = 1;
String s1 = "" + i;
String s2 = Integer.toString(i);
```

Using JDK 1.5.0_16 (ancient I know, but newer JDKs wouldn't be different I think), would compile to:

```
   0:   iconst_1
   1:   istore_1
   2:   new     #2; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   5:   dup
   6:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   9:   ldc     #4; //String
   11:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   14:  iload_1
   15:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   18:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   21:  astore_2
   22:  iload_1
   23:  invokestatic    #8; //Method java/lang/Integer.toString:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
   26:  astore_3
```

So when you are using `s1 = "" + i"`, what you're actually doing is:

```
s1 = new StringBuilder().append("").append(i).toString();
```

(which creates a new object and calls the `append(String)` followed by the `append(int)` method of `StringBuilder` and then converts it into a string.

So the likes of `Integer.toString(int)` are more efficient...

Comment: Thank you interesting to see what exactly the "" + x does.

Answer (score 2):

Casting has a specific meaning, which is to change the type of a reference, but never the type or contents of the referenced object.

`""+x` has a specific use case which only relates to Strings.  You can't convert to any other data type this way.

Java doesn't have concept of "casting" from one type of object to another.

Comment: ...and ""+x working at all might be considered by some to be a poor decision when the language was designed.

Comment: Given you can do `"a" + x` it seems logical to me, but many agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Casting an int to String is simply not possible in Java. In the expression:

```
functionThatRequiresString(""+x)
```

there is no casting, what happens is you call the + operator which returns String if one of it's argument's is a String.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't **cast** an `int` to a `String` because `String` is not a parent or child class of `int`.  Casting is about how you view an object in different related classes.

What you're really asking (I think) is why doesn't Java automatically **convert** between types for you?

The answer and the reason you can't do `functionThatRequiresString(x)` is because Java is [**type safe**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) and insists that you pass the values correct type to methods.  The benefit of this is that you don't get the hard to find kind of bugs where you're passing the wrong type to a function but it's being silently converted to the correct type, so you code compiles but acts very weird when run.  The downside, as you've seen, is that it's less convenient when you do want to perform a conversion.

The reason why can do things likes `"" + x` is because this is such a common operation the compiler handles all the conversion for you.  As you're explicitly creating a String here it's safe to do the conversion.

Comment: +1 Thank you, my understanding of casting was always that you are converting from one data type to another. So my understanding that it is not that simple of a definition.